# How to fill the bins?

Tags: distributions, quantiles, quantile-regression, binning

Consider 1 million people earning money, sorted in increasing order. The kth decile, i.e. the kth 100,000 of them has an income share of $f(k)$ with $f(k)<f(k+1)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{10} f(k)=1$. Let the total income be 10 billion units, so the average income is 10,000 units.

Comprehensive data on income share per quintile resp. centile are given by the [World Bank](http://datatopics.worldbank.org/world-development-indicators/themes/poverty-and-inequality.html#featured-indicators_1) ("Distribution of income or consumption") and look like this:

[image]

By cumulation one gets [Lorenz curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve) from which the [Gini index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) is calculated:

[image]

Now consider some ten income bins, for example these

0 < 5,000 < 10,000 < 20,000 < 50,000 < 100,000 < 200,000 < 500,000 < 1,000,000 < 2,000,000 < $\infty$

or these

0 < 1,000 < 3,000 < 10,000 < 30,000 < 100,000 < 300,000 < 1,000,000 < 3,000,000 < 10,000,000 < $\infty$

Assume for all but the last bin that the average income in that bin is the  middle of its range, i.e. 500 units for the first bin, 2,000 units for the second bin, and so on. Only for the last bin (with no specific upper bound) the average income in that bin cannot be estimated beforehand.

My question:

> How do I fill the bins, i.e. do I distribute the number of 1 million
>   people to the ten bins such that the decile data $f(k)$ result?

I assume there is a unique solution (assuming specific averages per bin), but how to find, resp. to construct it is unclear to me? Which specific and efficient algorithm should I choose? (Some pseudo code would be awesome!)

Comment: I feel your introduction to the question suggests something else than what you ask in the end. So may I ask if any of these interpretations are correct?:

(1): You are asking how to FILL your 10 groups computationally, given you have the borders of the 10 bins? 

(2): Or are you asking how to FIND the borders of the bins? (You want to recreate the same histogram you observe when binning with deciles, just you want to find the income-value that corresponds to those decile bins?

Comment: It's definitely (1). What could (2) mean? Bins can be chosen more or less arbitrarily - or not? Given are the bins' ranges (borders), their average incomes, and the data per deciles.

Comment: I deliberately chose ten bins because there are ten deciles.

Comment: I think I get it now: You do NOT have access to the individual incomes per single person; your data is based solely on the pictures you provided? So you need to assume a certain (maybe homogeneous) distribution of incomes in each decile with the aim of reshaping the data to bins of your choice? Am I getting closer?

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in 2 steps:

1. You recreate your "raw" data. (This takes critical
   assumptions!)
2. You take this "raw data" and bin it however you want.

Step 2 should be easy and you should readily find guides for how to do binned histograms so I will try to give some hints for how to approach point 1:

1. Distribute the total income to the 10 deciles of figure_1 to obtain the average income of the respective decile.
2. Now you need to assume a distribution. For example fully homogeneous or you try to mimic the histograms overall trend by finding a simple function that somewhat fits it. Also for the first and last bin, you have to take additional assumptions. In case of your first bin, maybe find a reference to the minimum wage.
3. Use these assumption to create your raw data:

Python Code:

```
import numpy as np
deciles = list of average wages in each decile from small to large
raw_wages = []
for i, average_wage in enumerate(deciles):
    if i != 0 & i != len(deciles):

        lower_limit = np.mean(deciles[i-1],deciles[i])
        upper_limit = np.mean(deciles[i],deciles[i+1])

        for wage in np.arange(lower_limit, upper_limit, difference/n):
            raw_wages.append(wage)
```

For the first and last bin, be creative!

I hope this helped!

Comment: Yes, this is a nice and straightforward approach which I already had thought about but didn't give it a second thought. Now you have encouraged me. This should work, and concerning the first and last bin (e.g. minimal and maximal income): these could be parameters of the game. I'll post my results!

Comment: Glad to hear! And if you need help with a non-linear approach, feel free to ask!

Comment: How critical do you think will the results depend on the assumptions: (a) concerning the inner-decile distribution (homogenuous, linear, best fitting) and (b) concerning the first and the last bin?

Comment: What would you suggest as the best approach to fitting: should I try to find a polynomial or exponential curve that fits the decile data points best? On what should this decision depend? And do you know an out-of-the-box method (Python or JavaScript) that for input = ten data points gives as output the parameters of the best-fitting k-th degree polynomial or exponential?

Comment: The assumptions for your last and first decile might not matter at all, if your subsequent wage-bins do not "test" them much! Also be aware that we are currently slightly changing the mean of each decile! Maybe you should divide each batch of wages of each decile by it's mean and then multiply with the actual mean. Maybe it's worth spending the time to model the single wages based on the fitting function. But for rough estimates this should suffice!

Comment: It would be optimal if the World Bank would have published their raw data (which they must have to calculate their published data, including the Gini index). But I could not find them - and I'm afraid they are undisclosed. (My whole excercise is to reconstruct the undisclosed raw data!) If you accidentally know where to find the World Bank's raw data I would not have to reconstruct them - but anyway, it's a revealing exercise.

Comment: I didn't want to make specific assumptions for the first and last *decile* (but to treat them like all the others) - assumptions have to be made for the first and last *bin*!

Comment: For fitting it's generally recommend to use a formula suggested by the literature of the field! I am sure at some point someone already did a fit and then you have a reference! For example f(x)-> a + b x^c or f(x)-> a + b^(x/c) and you have to fit by approximating the a,b and c. After you have the fit, this solves all problems for the first and last segment. Just follow the same formula!

Comment: But the "literature of the field" is vast! How to find the needle in the haystack?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100475/discussion-between-hans-peter-stricker-and-kapy3141).